# Program counter in ISA with multi-word size for instructions

Tags: cpu

Some ISA's have instructions that are multiple words, such as the MOV instruction in x86. How does the program counter behave in that case, if the instruction loaded is more than one word? For example, the 5 byte MOV eax, 0x11223344 in x86, encoded as B8 44 33 22 11. In the case of that example, I would assume PC (EPI register in x86 if I understand right) is incremented by two (4 byte + 4 byte, two words, assuming word size is 4 byte. ) I tried to test it myself in [this emulator](https://kobzol.github.io/davis/) , but it only increments by one. I assume emulator wrong. I ask broadly here because people here would likely know: How does the program counter behave (generally, across specific ISA's) if the instruction loaded is more than one word?

Comment: I'm not sure this is on-topic here.  Any community votes?  It might be appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why would it not be on topic?

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic here.  See our [help/on-topic].

Comment: Labelling this a "programming" question is a bit of a stretch, is it not?

Comment: That's up to the community to vote on, but my understanding is that questions about the details of a specific programming language or assembly language are generally considered out of scope here.  Such questions can be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why would {,E,R}IP be incremented by anything but the length of the instruction?

Comment: (Participant vote: Question is about one particular architecture&simulator. I think the architecture part on topic, the simulator one off.)

Comment: I don't really care about the simulator. I want to learn the basics of how a CPU works, x86 was used as an example by many people here, it was said that it could do different length instructions, I was interested in how that works with the program counter. As far as I understand, it would read 4 byte at a time. If it reads 5 byte, I assumed the counter would increment twice.

Comment: D.W. referenced x86 in a reply to a question I made. He mentioned that it did different length instructions. He (or she) knows this question is not a "programming question". Just an act.

Comment: I updated this question so that there is no sense that it is architecture specific or a "programming question". Peace

Comment: Instructions in x86 take up a whole number of bytes, not words. This instruction takes up 5 bytes (or 1 byte + 4 bytes if you choose to view it that way). The processor reads 1 byte at a time.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking it might be like that. So the program counter increments 5 times then for 5 byte?

Comment: Also thank you for your comment as it helps my question a lot.

Comment: When an instruction is fetched and executed, the PC is positioned on the address of the next instruction (either straight or as the result of a branch). But what is ISA ??

Comment: ISA = instruction set architecture? I want to learn basics of how CPU works, and therefore asked about this after learning about x86 "different length instructions". Then the question was labelled as being "too specific" and a "programing question", so I broadened it with the word "ISA".

Comment: (The other interpretation of ISA being *Industry Standard* Architecture - say, x86.)

Answer (score 1):

You have an instruction that is five bytes in size. After executing that instruction, what do you think where the next instruction is stored? Since the word size on a modern processor is 8 bytes, assume we have an instruction that is 11 bytes in size. Where do you think the next instruction is stored?

Comment: I assumed that the next was stored (if the instruction was larger than the word size) after the slots the instruction required. If it required two words, then after two. I state this in my question (I state where I think the next instruction is stored. ) But, now a user commented that the memory for instructions is addressed per-byte. And that the program counter would be incremented 5 times for 5 bytes.

Comment: Think about it: If you increased the PC by 8 bytes, what good would a 5 byte instruction do you? You might as well fill it with 3 more bytes of information.